# Need to extract a part of a number and save it in a variable in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, cut

Can you please help me with my query.
I am running a script .ksh with 2 arguments..one of which is a number like 14103 and I want to extract 1410 out of this number and save it in a variable.

Foe e.g:

```
abc.ksh ST 14103
```

What I am doing is:

```
#!/bin/ksh
ENV_TYPE=$1

VER=$2

VER_N=`cut -c1-4 "$VER"`
```

But it is not working for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want the first 4 characters, you do this entirely inside bash (which is a much better shell to use IMHO):

```
VER_N=${VER:0:4}

echo $VER_N
1410
```

If you mean you want all except the last character (again in bash):

```
n=${#VER}          # Get length of VER
((n--))            # Decrement
VER_N=${VER:0:$n}  # Extract all but last

echo $VER_N
1410
```

Or all but the last character, but using `sed`:

```
VER_N=$(sed 's/.$//' <<< $VER)
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `cut` does not use the text of its command line argument as the text to `cut`.

When a command line argument is given, it tries to interpret it as a filename and read that file.

If no argument is given, it reads from `stdin`. In your case, it is most simple to pipe the input into `cut`'s `stdin` rather than creating a temporary file and then asking `cut` to read it.

```
#!/bin/ksh
ENV_TYPE=$1

VER=$2

VER_N=`echo $VER | cut -c1-4 `

echo $VER_N
```

Output:

```
1410
```

Comment: You can also use `VER_N=$(cut -c-4 <<< "$VER")`. Note the 1 in `-c1-4` is superfluous.